# Peer exit immediatly after starting with "fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution" with Fabric1.4 on Ubuntu18.04

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, peer

I'm using **Fabric v1.4** on **Ubuntu 18.04.02LTS**. I installed everything on this machine this week following the tutorials, so I got the Samples, Binaries and Docker Images of v1.4 (latest), like:

```
hyperledger/fabric-peer        1.4.0               304fac59b501        5 weeks ago         157MB

hyperledger/fabric-peer        latest              304fac59b501        5 weeks ago         157MB
```

**This is my environment:**

curl            7.58.0

docker          18.06.1-ce

docker-compose  1.23.2

go              1.11.5

node            11.8.0

npm             6.5.0

python          2.7.15rc1

GOPATH=/home/tom/go

GOROOT=/usr/local/go

PATH=/home/tom/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

This is what I'm doing to start the basic network (the same happens with the other networks, like byfn) and what happens:

[Starting basic network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmv7E.png)

The network fails at starting because it's impossible to reach the peer. Actually, the peer exited a few seconds after starting.

This is the peer log:

[Peer0.Org1 logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf3h1.png)

I tried to reinstall dependencies, to kill containers and networks and to remove and download images but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try adding GODEBUG=netdns=go to your environment sections of your peers/orderers in your docker-compose file

Comment: Could you provide some information about the issue? Also how to be in production?

Comment: This solved my problem. Could you please explain what this does?

Answer (score 0):

- Stop all containers
- run `docker system prune -a`
- clone the fabric sample repo
- checkout v1.4 tag
- then try again with starting your network

If you still have the same problem, then it could be because of your docker version.

Comment: I did what suggested but I get the same error.
I uninstalled docker and installed with
    sudo apt install docker.io
and I have version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a, which should be ok, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: make sure you have the right GO-version for fabric 1.4 and make sure that you installed GO correctly on your machine.

Comment: try adding GODEBUG=netdns=go to your environment sections of your peers/orderers in your docker-compose file

Comment: Thank you @david_k, it worked with GODEBUG=netdns=go in the peer requisites in docker-compose.yml file! do I have to change some other settings?